# Unable to access "Boot Menu"on windows XP and MSI motherboard

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, motherboard, bootable-media

I have windows XP SP2 & MSI motherboard, but i am unable to know how i can access the Boot Menu on windows start.

Currently when i start my windows, i do not have the option to access the Boot Menu. 
I need this as i am facing a problem on my AVG anti virus  and i need to disable it using a bootable USB, and currently my windows XP will keep restarting as the AVG is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post the exact motherboard (it will be written on the board somewhere if you don't still have the box or other documentation to hand) as the BIOS used may have varied over time and/or between chipsets so the keys to press to get into the config menu vary.

If you can't get into the BIOS then you may be able to disable AVG in star mode. To get into that press F8 early in the windows startup (just before the logo first shows) and safe mode should be an option on that menu.